# Don't show empty parent category in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have parent and child categories on the page. What I'm trying to do is when there is no products and no sub-categories assigned in some parent category to not be shown on the page.

So I have this in Category model

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Item','category_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}


public function getCategories()
{
    $categoires = Category::where('parent_id',0)->get();
    $categoires = $this->addRelation($categoires);
    return $categoires;
}

public function selectChild( $id )
{
    $categoires = Category::where('parent_id',$id)->where('published', 1)->get();
    $categoires = $this->addRelation($categoires);
    return $categoires;
}
```

This in the controller

```
public function index()
{
    $Category = new Category;
    $allCategories = $Category->getCategories();
    return view('frontend.home', compact('allCategories', 'unviewedMessagesCount'));
}
```

And this on the blade view

```
@foreach($allCategories as $category)
    {!!$category->title!!} ({!! $category->itemCount!!})
    <p class="card-text">
      @foreach($category->subCategory as $subcategory)
        {!!$subcategory->title!!} {!! $subcategory->itemCount !!}
      @endforeach
    </p>
    <a href="{!!route('list',array($category->id))!!}" class="btn btn-primary">View Category</a>
@endforeach
```

This is sample of the records in category table there are column

```
id | title     | parent
 1    Main cat     0
 2    Sub-Cat      1
 3    Sub-Cat 2    1
 4    Main cat 2   0
```

So each parent is 0 and each child(sub category) has the parent ID

`item` table has also reference to `category` table -> column `category_id`

I can't figured it out how to make the condition if no items and no childs to not show it on page.

Comment: You can do it like this `$categoires = Category::has('children')->has('children.item')->where('parent_id',0)->get();`

Comment: @Maraboc, thanks but not found column error occurred  `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pare‌​nt_id' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 1):

In Controller

```
$allCategories = Category::where('parent_id', 0)->has('children.item')
                ->with(['children'=> function($query){
                    $query->withCount('item');
                }])
                ->get()
                ->each(function($parentCategory){
                    // if you wants calculate sum child category item count and assign to parent category item_count.
                    $parentCategory->item_count = $parentCategory->children->sum(function ($child) { return isset($child->item_count)?$child->item_count:0;});
                });
return view('frontend.home', compact('allCategories'));
```

In this query only one query will be executed and it return all of your needs.

And In Blade View file

```
@foreach($allCategories as $category)
    {!!$category->title!!} ({!! $category->item_count!!})
    <p class="card-text">
    @foreach($category->children as $subcategory)
        {!!$subcategory->title!!} {!! $subcategory->item_count !!}
    @endforeach
    </p>
    <a href="{!!route('list',array($category->id))!!}" class="btn btn-primary">View Category</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay. I have tried your suggestion but I've got `Class 'Item' not found`

Comment: Sorry this is the error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'children.item_count' in 'field list' (SQL: select sum(`children`.`item_count`) as aggregate from `categories`)`

Comment: it's hided empty main&sub categories but if I have 5 sub-categories and I assigned item to 1 of them then it's showing all of them. Must show Main category name + this one sub-category which has item assigned.. not all of them

Comment: Also if the item is assigned to main category only this main category isn't visible on the page. Above code showing categories on page only if the product is in sub-category